# Android Studio functions of alert dialog in another java class

Tags: java, android

In my **MainActivity.Java**, I have an `onClickListener` in a button that will show an Alert Dialog when it's clicked

```
scanbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View scanPopup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scan_tab, null);

            forScan.setView(scanPopup);
            dialog = forScan.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

This is is the **ScanTab.Java** wherein the AlertDialog will have its functions

```
package com.example.AppDraft1.activity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.AppDraft1.MainActivity;
import com.example.AppDraft1.R;
import com.example.AppDraft1.parser.NdefMessageParser;
import com.example.AppDraft1.record.ParsedNdefRecord;

import java.util.List;

public class ScanTab extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private TextView text;
    private String first, surname, id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_tab);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, this.getClass())
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled())
                showWirelessSettings();

            nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (nfcAdapter != null){
            nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs;

            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }

            } else {
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
            }

            displayMsgs(msgs);
        }
    }

    private void displayMsgs(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0)
            return;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
        final int size = records.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);
            String str = record.str();
            builder.append(str).append("\n");
        }

        text.setText(builder.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Tag Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        sndData();
    }
    public void sndData(){

        String theText = text.getText().toString();

        //split data
        String[] split = theText.split("/",3);
        first = split[0];     //first name
        surname = split[1];   //surname
        id = split[2];        //id number

        Intent intent = new Intent(ScanTab.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FName", first);
        intent.putExtra("SName", surname);
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showWirelessSettings() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enable NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private String dumpTagData(Tag tag) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] id = tag.getId();
        sb.append("ID (hex): ").append(toHex(id)).append('\n');
        sb.append("ID (reversed hex): ").append(toReversedHex(id)).append('\n');
        sb.append("ID (dec): ").append(toDec(id)).append('\n');
        sb.append("ID (reversed dec): ").append(toReversedDec(id)).append('\n');

        String prefix = "android.nfc.tech.";
        sb.append("Technologies: ");
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            sb.append(tech.substring(prefix.length()));
            sb.append(", ");
        }

        sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());

        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                String type = "Unknown";

                try {
                    MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);

                    switch (mifareTag.getType()) {
                        case MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC:
                            type = "Classic";
                            break;
                        case MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS:
                            type = "Plus";
                            break;
                        case MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO:
                            type = "Pro";
                            break;
                    }
                    sb.append("Mifare Classic type: ");
                    sb.append(type);
                    sb.append('\n');

                    sb.append("Mifare size: ");
                    sb.append(mifareTag.getSize() + " bytes");
                    sb.append('\n');

                    sb.append("Mifare sectors: ");
                    sb.append(mifareTag.getSectorCount());
                    sb.append('\n');

                    sb.append("Mifare blocks: ");
                    sb.append(mifareTag.getBlockCount());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    sb.append("Mifare classic error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (tech.equals(MifareUltralight.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareUltralight mifareUlTag = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
                        type = "Ultralight";
                        break;
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
                        type = "Ultralight C";
                        break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Ultralight type: ");
                sb.append(type);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
            if (b < 0x10)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String toReversedHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
            if (b < 0x10)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private long toDec(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private long toReversedDec(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;


    }
}
```

When I tested it, the view is working but the functions are absent. How do I embed or make the functions work in the AlertDialog?

Answer (score 0):

Alert Dialogs are meant to 'alert' the user of something, or run code based on input from user in case of input dialog.
If you want to run code in the alert dialog, you can run it before setView of dialog.

Additionally it is not recommended to block user from interacting with app using an Alert Dialog.

If you want to run code from one activity in another, in your case run code in ScanActivity from MainActivity the best way I can think of is Activity RESULTS API which replaced StartActivityForResult [[read here]](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

But I would just recommended you start ScanActivity and show the dialog from there, then you can easily call all methods of ScanActivity.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't think you answered my question. In my alert dialog, the only thing that will appear is a single TextView, so the code in ScanTab.Java are all for the functions.

Comment: What the ScanTab.Java does is this, it allows me to read data in NFC Tags (kind of like a card reader) when it is close to my phone (through electromagnetic waves). So I want this kind of function in my alert dialog.

Comment: Yes exactly, how do I do that? How do I run the code in ScanTab.java in my Alert Dialog?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I thought of calling all methods but I didn't know how to call the rest like methods with `protected void onNewIntent` ` private String toHex` and others (Sorry still a newbie). Though I'll try it. Thanks for the help! I'll get back to you in a few days!